# difference between :nth-child(even) and :even in jquery

Tags: jquery

`:nth-child(even)` and `:even` in jquery are looking similar but selecting different elements. Please let me know the differences.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/bEfT6/

`:even` matches every 2nd element within the set of elements you are selecting.  Where as `:nth-child(even)` matches any elements which are an even numbered child of their respective parent.

So in the example, you see that the two selectors affect different elements.  The elements with red text match the selected class and are even numbered children of the parent div.  The ones with blue background match the selected class and are even within that selection.

So:

```
.something:nth-child(odd)
```

matches every element with the class `something` which is an even child of it's parent.

```
.something:even
```

matches every other element with the class `something`.  (regardless of relation to its siblings)

Comment: Thanks kingjiv, Its a great example, gave me the answer in neat and clear manner

Answer (score 3):

`:even` is 0-based, while `:nth-child` is 1-based. This is from the docs for `:even`

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that, counter-intuitively, :even selects the first element, third element, and so on within the matched set.

This is for `:nth-child`

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth-child(n) is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1. For all other selector expressions, however, jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting.

Comment: While this is true, this is a minor difference.  The two selectors are conceptually different.

Comment: The fiddle you just posted contradicts that statement.  Some of the elements have both effects and some have only one.

Comment: @kingjiv: You are right - in FF they are exactly the same, but in Chrome - not so. This seems like a bug in jQuery or Firefox?

Comment: Don't have FF at the moment to look, but if that is the case it would seem like a definite bug.  The result in chrome is the correct result as far as I understand the two.